# How to Decrypt Encrypted UPD Client Data?

Tags: sockets, server, client, protocols, public-key-encryption

I am building a UPD Server and I've already hooked the game client up to it and im now receiving data. The only problem is that the client data I'm receiving looks encrypted (I found the game has a public key and needs it). I am just wondering what would I need to do to decrypt this data, since its UPD Im not sure about TLS/SSL. Any help is appreciated Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to help based on these information. The usefulness of these information is similar to "I've found a green car on the street but don't have any keys for it nor any clue how to drive - please help".

Comment: I've got the Public key and Private Key that were generated using a 2048 rsa. I was just wondering would i just decrypt the client data with rsa or use something like DTLS

Comment: *"...that were generated using a 2048 rsa..."* - The green car now has a pink steering wheel but the information did not get any more useful. What you need is a specification of the protocol which is spoken.